# How is the access token used in the Composer Rest Server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

What is the intended purpose of the Loopback Access Token on the Fabric Composer REST server Explorer? Can this be used to identify the participant invoking a transaction and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The LoopBack access token field has been removed from the Composer REST server as a result of recent restyling work, but the access token is still important.

You can enable REST API authentication for the Composer REST server by following this documentation:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

When you configure the Composer REST server this way, each authenticated user gets their own private wallet on the Composer REST server to store Blockchain identities (enrolment certificates). The Composer REST server uses a Blockchain identity from the authenticated users private wallet to submit all REST API calls to the Blockchain.

This means that we can use the authenticated users Blockchain identity to identify the participant, and correctly apply ACL rules.

When you authenticate to the Composer REST server, LoopBack generates an access token that you can use to interact with the REST API from any HTTP client without having to login again. This is useful as it is difficult to automate the OAuth web browser flow from within a computer program.

We do not show the access token on the Composer REST server UI, but you can access it by looking at the cookies that get stored in your web browser after authenticating to the Composer REST server. You can then use this from your HTTP client by appending the query string parameter `access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` to the URL, or sending in by HTTP header `access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN`.

We need more documentation on this though!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Simon Stone. Can you please also advice, If I'm **using `node` env, how can I fetch the `access_token` from the cookies** (Since it does not seem to show it). The cookies seem to have only `ga` & `connect.sid`. Morever even using browser, I cannot see the `access_token` as part of the stored cookies. I can view it only if I directly see the request headers properties under Chrome "Network" tab

Comment: @Simon Stone the provided link results with the issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814851/hyperledger-composer-error-authenticating-to-the-rest-server

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Are you able to get access_token? I am also stuck with the same issue