# Hyperledger Composer :error Authenticating to the REST server

Tags: oauth, hyperledger-composer

I have been following this Hyperledger Composer tutorial
 [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html) and when I try to authenticate to the rest server via http://localhost:3000/auth/github I am not being redirected to the GitHub site to perform the OAuth web server authentication flow. Instead of redirecting, I am getting a 404 error message.
Expected Behavior

According to the Composer tutorial, I would expect being redirected to the Github site to perform the OAuth.
Actual Behavior

When I enter http://localhost:3000/auth/github I am getting a 404 error

My environment:

docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

node --version
v6.11.0

Adding more details for reference...

[image: Actul error i am facing]

[[image: github Oaath application setup[3]]

[image: composer rest server unauthorized error- expected]]

[image: Rest client for the oath token set up]

[image: Rest client exception]

EDIT:

here is complete error stack trace:

Unhandled error for request GET /explorer/auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /explorer/auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate. (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)
Unhandled error for request GET /explorer/auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /explorer/auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate. (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)
Unhandled error for request GET /explorer/auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /explorer/auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate. (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)
Unhandled error for request GET /explorer/auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /explorer/auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate. (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)
Unhandled error for request GET /explorer/auth/github: Error: Cannot GET /explorer/auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate. (/home/brankoterzic/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)

Comment: I suspect you have a typo of configuration problem somewhere. Can you post more information please.

Comment: Hi Dan, As per documentation added following configuration to command line before starting the composer server..export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "github": {
    "provider": "github",
    "module": "passport-github",
    "clientID": "005a2f35918f55975961",
    "clientSecret": "d7de9359c496108e07903b3f3f3c3f503130fbf4",
    "authPath": "/auth/github",
    "callbackURL": "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect": "/"
  }
}'

Answer (score 1):

Check if your github account is private. I created a new github account, and it works. Also use the latest command:

> composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -a
>   true

instead of the -S one

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS stanza - specifically the callbackURL setting - you don't need the localhost:3000 - you just need the URL path as "/auth/github/callback" shown in the docs : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html . The REST server will take care of..the rest.. . Then stop and restart the composer REST server `composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -S true` etc  - from the command line where you export the configuration variable COMPOSER_PROVIDERS (above). cheers Paul

Comment: Still facing the same issue, I guess simple exporting a variable over command line is not working..any clues do we have different options over here to make sure this configuration is picked up?

Comment: Facing the same issue, is there any progress to this?

Comment: can you post your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS stanza in a code block please? Need to see it to comment, thanks.

Comment: Aslo, before enabling the REST authentication, my API root was like this: http://localhost:3000/api/User. After enabling it, when I try to use the same API, I get the same error, as posted in the question. Then I released, that API changed to http://localhost:3000/api/com.myapp.User, and after hitting this a get the 200 ok answer without need for authentication.

Comment: Here si COMPOSER-PROVIDERS env:

{
  "github": {
    "provider": "github",
    "module": "passport-github",
    "clientID": "714035408fe6f0274c06",
    "clientSecret": "b03490c40d8eea219ff312b1b8f95b37630e43f6",
    "authPath": "/auth/github",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect": "/"
  }
}