# Hyperledger-Composer REST Authentication

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Request assistance with hyperledger composer. I have created a network and web app around the REST API that was built with the composer-rest-server. I am able to add participants, assets and execute transaction with the default settings. I am now trying to add authentication to the REST server as well as add identities to new participants. However I got stuck. I have reviewed the information at

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

But I'm not sure where I should place the export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{.... information to continue the setup.

Any assistance, tips and tricks are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it out. The problem was that I was running off an older version of composer-rest-server.

I installed the developer tool back in Sep 17 and did the tutorial soon after. I tried the tutorial again and noticed that the deployment command was different and it would not let me deploy my network.

So I updated the composer-rest-server and component cli and it deployed fine. I then followed the steps on the authentication webpage that I referenced above and it worked as intended. I deployed my personal network with the new command and it worked as intended.

Lesson learned this stuff is still being updated and I should be more aware on what changes. Thank you very much @nilakantha singh deo

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal from inside the project folder.Format your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS in notepad according to the document you mentioned and copy the whole message and paste it in the terminal.Then you can echo it (see it) by typing the following.

```
echo $COMPOSER_PROVIDERS
```

It should ideally return the same json file.
Then make sure that the compopser-rest-server is running with multiuser mode and authentication enabled in the same terminal where you echoed and saw the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS.
In browser now type

```
localhost:3000/auth/github
```

It should ask for authentication .Rest of the steps are listed in the document you mentioned.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to get the right echo response but I still don't get the 401 error after I launch the server with the given command. I'll take some screen shots to see if you have any other recommendations for me. Thanks again  https://ibb.co/mSnvyG
https://ibb.co/j77HCb
https://ibb.co/f2WNdG

Comment: 401 comes at localhost:3000/explorer .Are you able to see github authentication page at localhost:3000/auth/github  ?

Comment: Do you have passport-github installed?Make sure to run composer-rest-server in the same terminal where you are echoing COMPOSER_PROVIDERS.Try adding -m true to your command and check.

Comment: Yes I have the passport-github installed (npm install -g passport-github). I get a 404 error when I go to 3000/auth/github and I am in the same terminal. I double checked my clientId and clientsecret and even created a new git hub account and still no authentication what so ever. I also read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814851/hyperledger-composer-error-authenticating-to-the-rest-server to get some ideas but I'm getting a 200 response code when I run get commands on my participants. Once again thank you for your patients and help.

Comment: Could you please try with this command >>composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -N never -a true -m true -w true   ;replace my-network with your network name.

Comment: Still nothing sir. 
Here is some of my project background and the step I'm taking
(ibx): project folder (this would be my-network from the tutorial)
(ibx/IBX): angular project (this would be my-app from the tutorial)

Open terminal and go to cd to (ibx)
paste the Composer_Providers line from the website where I add my clientID and clientSecret
Run $Composer_Providers to verify the previous line
Run composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n ibx -i admin -s adminpw -N never -a true -m true -w true (ibx is my network)

Comment: I go to localhost:3000/explorer and run a get or post on the server it returns with status code 200
I go to localhost:3000/auth/github I get a 404 error
I go to localhost:3000/explorer/auth/github I get a 404 error

Comment: Please follow this link.https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html dont customize ,just copy paste the given code in your local folder and replicate the steps.You will find the error for sure.